# cmd prompt not compling my java files

Tags: java, compiler-errors, command-prompt, .class-file

I am using eclipse for my project , when i am running eclipse , my project work the way i wanted but when i tried to run on command prompt , i realize it is using the old .class file which is compiled earlier. But i have already complied by using javac *.java but the class file isn't generated when i delete the class file.

my src folder have this files :

Project.java

Admin Folder ( user.java , staff.java , Teacher.java , Module.java) they are all package Admin;

in my project.java

i do `import Admin.Module;`

the Teacher.java class file not generated when i compile , in my Module.java i used user,staff,Teacher classes in my code. Project.java is just a default package where i can easily just type java Project to run in cmd.

i compile in cmd prompt like this : javac Project.java , i suppose it will also compile the packages and files that is being used also but the class file isn't generated.

Comment: any messages from javac?

Comment: nope. it compiiled successfully but no class file generated @piet.t

Answer (score 0):

You need to compile all module file seperatly.
**javac Admin/Teacher.java**
If in Teacher .java main() method exist then you can directly check Teacher.java using below cmd :-
**java Admin.Teacher**

then you can import this on your project.java file.
Hope it can help you